# Matrix analogue of Fermat's little theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrices with entries from a field of characteristic $p$. Is it true that Tr$(A)=0$ if only if Tr$(A^p)=0$?

Comment: The matrix analogue of Fermat's little theorem is that $\text{tr}(A^p) \equiv \text{tr}(A) \bmod p$ if $A$ has integer entries. There is a cute combinatorial proof of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be a matrix over the field $K$ and $\overline{K}$ the algebraic closure of $K$. $A$ has $n$ eigenvalues (counted with algebraic multiplicity) $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in\overline{K}$ and
$ \text{trace}(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i $ while $ \text{trace}(A^p) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^p = \text{trace}(A)^p$. So your claim follows.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but for $p = 2$, we have $\textrm{tr}\left[\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}^2\right] = \textrm{tr} \,I_ 2 = 0$, and for odd $p$, we have $\textrm{tr}\left[\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}^p\right] = \textrm{tr}\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} = 0$.

Comment: @Travis: You are absolutely right. I was careless. The answer is corrected now and in fact your claim is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. Let $\$K$ be your base field of characteristic $p>0$, and let $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n\in\bar{K}$ (an algebraic closure of $K$) be the eigenvalues of $A\in M_n(K)$.
By trigonalisation of $A$ in $M_n(\bar{K})$, we see that

$tr(A)=\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_n$, while 
$$tr(A^p)=\lambda_1^p+\cdots+\lambda_n^p=(\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_p)^p=tr(A)^p$$ since $K$ (and therefore $\bar{K}$) has characteristic $p$. Since we are working over a field, we have $$tr(A^p)=0\iff tr(A)^p=0\iff tr(A)=0.$$

Comment: I do not understand why $tr(A^p) = tr(A)^p$. I only know a proof of the result you have used in the case that the eigenvalues are integers. Could you provide a reference for why raising the sum to the power of $p$ is the same as raising each eigenvalue to the power of $p$?

Comment: In any commutative ring $R$ of characteristic $p$, one has $(a+b)^p=a^p+ b^p$ for all $a,b\in R.$ This comes from the fact that $p$ divides the non-extremal binomial coefficients in the binomial expansion of $(a+b)^p$.